# Can I use a Mask R-CNN to detect a skin texture?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, python, mask-rcnn

I'm trying to implement a solution in python to detect skin in an image.

I'm evaluating the Mask R-CNN model to create a mask on the skin (not on clothes). The problem is that every solution I have encountered using Mask R-CNN uses it to classify objects. I'm afraid that using it trying to classify texture might be a problem. Is it the case?

My dataset is actually pretty good, composed of the

1. original image,
2. precise mask on the skin, and
3. grounding box.

Can I use a Mask R-CNN to detect a skin texture?